# Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am learning android development and facing problems while building the project.
I am making a calculator app:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.palakjain.simplecalculator.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <!--<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnErase"
            android:text="<-"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:text="C"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPercentage"
            android:text="%"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDivide"
            android:text="/"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMul"
            android:text="X"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSub"
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPoint"
            android:text="."
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
            android:text="="
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is what I have done in my XML file and I am not able to figure out what's wrong. Kindly help.

Comment: Post your full layout xml and logcat.

Comment: Your root linear layout is not closed.

Comment: Seems your layout is OK. Can you please post your MainActivity.java?

Comment: I have rebuilt the project and it's working fine now...and I don't know why...lol..anyway thanks:)

Comment: can we use android:text="<-" in a Button?

Comment: @PalakJain, yes, we can, other way how do you set the text on the button?

Comment: @PalakJain NO, it will give you an error "Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)"

Comment: Check my updated answer to show "<-" on Button.

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko, I used android:text="sometext" attribute to set text on button

Comment: @FAT..using "<-" may have been the reason for getting that error (error parsing XML)!!

Comment: @PalakJain, and what is the problem?

Comment: @VladMatvienko The problem has been resolved...thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use attribute `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `btnClear` instead of `match_parent` to show `btnPercentage` and `btnDivide` on screen.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClear"
        android:text="C"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPercentage"
        android:text="%"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDivide"
        android:text="/"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, `Clean` and `Rebuild` your project and `Run` again.

**UPDATE:**

> Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) in Android

I guess this problem is occurring due to `android:text="<-"`. If you want to show `"<-"` as `Text` on `Button`, then use below code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClear"
    android:text="&lt;-"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

FYI, here `&lt;` represents `<`. Hope this will work~

Comment: @Palak Jain: Thanks for accepting my answer. If my answer seems useful, i hope you will give an up-vote. Thanks in advance :)